# Cannot call a class method with [self theMethod:]

Tags: objective-c, methods, class-method

I am trying to write a class method in Objective C. The project builds fine when I declare the method. But the build fails whenever I try to call the method. Here is my code.

**Header File**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController {
    //Declare Vars
}
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender;
+ (NSString *) md5Hash:(NSString *)str;
@end
```

**Source File**

```
+ (NSString *) md5Hash:(NSString *)str {
    const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
        result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
        result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
        result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
        result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
        ];
}
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender {
        //Call the class method
        [self md5Hash:@"Test"];
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You should call it like this:

```
[LoginViewController md5Hash:@"Test"];
```

Because it's a class (**LoginViewController**) method and not an instance (**self**) method.

Comment: Sure -- and the key is to embrace that you aren't writing Java code.  Objective-C does not have static methods;  it has class methods, which can be overridden and otherwise behave exactly like instance methods (where the class is an instance of the metaclass).

Comment: You should use `[[self class] md5Hash]` otherwise subclasses will have trouble if they want their overrided `md5Hash:` to be called from `login:`.

Answer (score 33):

Or you could do:

```
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender {
        //Call the static method
        [[self class] md5Hash:@"Test"];
}
```

which should be exactly the same as calling [LoginViewController md5Hash:@"Test"] directly with the class name. Remember that md5Hash is a CLASS method, not an instance one, so you can't call it in objects (instances of the class), but from the class itself.

Answer (score 13):

you call static methods on the class, and not on the instance. So should be

```
- (IBAction) login: (id) sender {
        //Call the static method
        [LoginViewController md5Hash:@"Test"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` symbol indicates that you are declaring a class method. You should replace it with `-`. The minus sign denotes the instance method. After that you can call it with `self`object.

```
- (NSString *) md5Hash:(NSString *)str;
```

and

```
- (NSString *) md5Hash:(NSString *)str {
    const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result );

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X;...... source code continued
}
```

Comment: while correct, this does not answer the OP question, which is how to call static methods from an instance method of the same class (and without specifying the class name)