# Static method (which isn't class method) in objective C

Tags: objective-c, static-methods, class-method

While reading [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089186/objective-c-difference-between-class-method-and-static-method) question and accepted answer for the question, I was unable to get the difference between these two types of methods. Actually got the point by reading the example, but then, I was not able to write my own static method.

I tried googling *create static method in objective c static methods*

Which returned me links to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691383/how-can-i-make-a-static-method-in-objective-ci) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585560/objective-c-static-method) question. But, the example here are *CLASS methods* as per the first link in the question. Which is confusing me.

Can anyone here show me how do I create a *static method* which is not a *class method* ?

Any light on this would be appreciated.

Comment: A static method ***is*** a class level access method. This difference is "nothing". However, you can make global, static ***c-style*** methods which are static yet not part of a class

Comment: What do u mean bu static method outside class? How it can be different by normal method?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem you are having is the following - **there are no static methods in Obj-C**, that's why you cannot create them.

The difference between static and class methods is a difference between language concepts. You can find static methods in languages like Java or C++, you will find class methods in languages like Obj-C and Ruby.

The principal difference is that

1. Static methods are shared between all instances (this doesn't exist in Obj-C). They are dispatched statically (at compile time) depending on the type of the *variable*.
2. Class method is a method on a class. In languages like Obj-C and Ruby a class itself is an instance of another class (metaclass). Using `+` before a method declaration means the method will be defined on the class. Technically, it's just an instance method, just on a different object.

Don't worry if you don't understand the concept of class method perfectly, it takes time. To simplify, you can consider it as a method shared between instances, but it can be overriden in subclasses.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the information. I was really confused about it. I thought for a second that, If *static method* would exist, I should have found it somewhere. Thanks again.

Comment: +1 for the ruby reference. I think it helps to keep reminding people that it does not help to understanding Objective-C by placing it in company with  Java, C++ and C#. It is easier to compare to python, ruby and smalltalk.